# For $f$ analytic on some domain with condition, $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}f(n)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ixn}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am stuck on this question:

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |\text{Im}(z)| < b\}$ for some $b > 0$, and there exists a constant $A > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
|f(x + iy)| \leq \dfrac{A}{1 + x^2} 
\end{align*}
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|y| < b$. Prove that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ixn}dx\bigg)
\end{align*}

I was thinking of considering a complex function which has residues at every integer point, but I am not sure how to do it. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: This is the *Poisson Summation Formula*.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: I think the point is that there's an easier proof than the usual one since the hypotheses on $f$ are stronger. If I remember correctly, it follows from a clever contour integration.

Comment: The idea is to consider the integral of $\frac{f(z)}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}$ over the rectangle with vertices $-N-\frac{1}{2}\pm ia,N+\frac{1}{2}\pm ia$ where $0<a<b$ is fixed, and take $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @carmichael561Thank you for your hint! I still have trouble getting the R.H.S. term of what I want to prove. I know with the integral and contour considered, we have the integral over the parts of the rectangle that have real parts $x = N + 1/2$ and $x = -N - 1/2$ to tends to zero as $N \to \infty$, but I am not sure how to manipulate the integral over the horizontal line segments of the rectangle to achieve the term on the R.H.S

Comment: Expand $\dfrac{1}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}$ into a geometric series, interchange summation and integration, then use Cauchy's integral theorem to move the integration to the real axis.